# Error with Merge Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to create a merge sort algorithm in C++ that takes a Vector of a generic type as its input and sorts the elements in the Vector.
Except i am getting a **[run] Bus error (core dumped)** error everytime i try to test the algorithm.

My Code for the Merge Sort is as Follows:

```
template <typename T>
void merge_sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
typename std::vector<T>::iterator middle_value = vector.begin()+vector.size()/2;        std::vector<T> left_side(vector.begin(), middle_value);
    std::vector<T> right_side(middle_value,vector.end());
    merge_sort(left_side);
    merge_sort(right_side);
    std::vector<T> merged;
    int i,j;
    while(i<left_side.size() && j<right_side.size())
    {
    if(left_side.at(i)<right_side.at(j))
    {
        merged.push_back(left_side.at(i));
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        merged.push_back(right_side.at(j));
        j++;
    }
    }
    while(i<left_side.size())
    {
        merged.push_back(left_side.at(i));
        i++;
    }
    while(j<right_side.size())
    {
        merged.push_back(right_side.at(j));
        j++;
    }
    for(int x=0;x<merged.size();x++)
    vector.at(x)=merged.at(x);


}
```

Any Light on this issue would help very much.

Comment: `i` and `j` are not properly initialized. I think you meant to set them to zero: `int i = 0; int j = 0;`.

Comment: Also, when your vector is empty (which it will inevitably be at some point in the recursion), you need to stop. There seems to be no precaution taken against this in your code.

Comment: Ty you so much jogoJapan, yes it was such silly mistake on my part to forget that piece of code. But it is fixed when i added it to check for vector size.